# Interactive graphs in PDF file with Latex?

Tags: graphics, pdftex, pdf

There are several questions which are asking similar question, but not exactly.

I'm looking for a tool/method in Latex to generate really interactive graphs, when by dragging something on the graph it will be automatically redrawn or another graph will be redrawn. I saw this features in lectures [non-linear optics](https://www.coursera.org/learn/physique-optique/lecture/6Ts9C/absorption-et-indice-de-refraction-1-3) (see minute 7:05). I believe that professor's presentation was made with beamer package. He was able by tracking cursor redraw dynamically graph above. 
How did he do it?

[image]

There is another example: [latex2html5](http://latex2html5.com/), but for web.

What is the `Latex` way of doing this kind of stuff?

P.S.
It does not look as if he did many graphs and then update pdf page, it looks as if graph is continuously changing.

Comment: You might search around for the works by D.P. Story, who counts as THE expert when it comes to Latex and PDF.

Comment: We have to watch the whole lecture to find the graph? Really! Can ***you*** alter the graph in the PDF? If not, what makes you think the PDF supports this? The author might do a couple of things: prepare different graphs and animate the dragging etc. (This is, I think, most likely.) Otherwise, I'm guessing it is done using something like javascript (see the Story suggestion though a lot of that stuff requires Adobe software for integration with the server etc.). I don't think PDF itself is capable of this.

Comment: @cfr please see at 7:05 min. It does not look as if he did many graphs and then update pdf page, it looks as if graph is continuously changing. maybe you are right that javascript is right choice.

Comment: Can you alter the graphs in the PDF, though? But, as I say, if they are being altered, I think javascript or similar must be used. While it would be great to be wrong, I just don't think PDF itself can do this.

Comment: This is not really PDF but PDF & JavaScript or even PDF & HTML5.

Comment: The problem is: The JavaScript engine as implemented in AdobeReader and in another very few PDF readers doesn't provide a Canvas object on which one could freely draw upon.

Comment: This question will probably attract better informed answers on Stack Overflow, where there is the Javascript expertise needed to address this kind of PDF interactivity.  I don't think that PGF/Beamer expertise is relevant at all here.

Comment: Why do you think Beamer was used?

Comment: @CharlesStewart, I asked author of this slide and he answered "I actually write my slides in LaTeX/Beamer, with the java-code (pseudo-code)  hidden inside the LaTeX code"