# Is there a "Timed Text" package?

Tags: packages, pdf, accessibility

[Timed text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timed_text)  is a text that is synchronized with another source, typically as subtitle of a video. Is there a related  \LaTeX package? Can PDFLaTeX output be made to "scroll up" according to  certain time-stamps in the source file.  That is, can we insert certain time-stamps in a \LaTeX code so that the output PDF shows up in a rectangle, with a  highlight for the current segment in the middle of rectangle, and PDF scrolls up in real time according to some time-tags.

This post, on [simulating terminal output](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37869/10827), comes close.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266005/interactive-graphs-in-pdf-file-with-latex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a “Timed Text” package?

Not as far as I know.

> Can PDFLaTeX output be made to "scroll up" according to certain time-stamps in the source file?

It probably could, [dvisvgm](https://dvisvgm.de/) would be your friend, [SVG can be included in PDF](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/info/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf).

The case of embedding a video with subtitles is something else to me. This can be done with package [`media9`](https://ctan.org/pkg/media9?lang=de). This package can include `SMIL` (Synchronized Multimedia Integration Language) files. But you would have to produce the SMIL in another program.

However, you tagged your question with `accessibility` and from this point of view interaction in PDF is strongly discouraged. Such a PDF would not adhere to the PDF/UA standard for accessible documents because interaction is forbidden. How would a braille display handle a moving rectangle? Or a screen reader?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. The accessibility issue is in regard to providing a transcript for the deaf in sync with a video. The issue also comes up for translation into another language for the hearing.

Comment: @Maesmi I adjusted my answer to cover your comment.